# StorageProgress Report function is not called by GetFileAsync

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download resources file for my game from Firebase Storage, and to show downloading progress. But I came to strange behavior of GetFileAsync function. The Report function of StorageProgress is not called periodically during file downloading how it is described in reference. Report function is called during saving to disk, after the file is placed into memory(downloaded). What I'm doing wrong?

```
    string resourcesURL = "URL_TO_RESOURCE_FILE"; // https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/......    
    public void UpdateProgress(float val)
    {
        labelProgress.text = Mathf.RoundToInt(val * 100f) + "%";
        circleProgress.fillAmount = val;
    }

    void OnDownloadClick()
    {
        SetDownloadingView();
        string saveToPath = GetParentFolder() + "/resources.bin";

        StorageReference fileRef = FirebaseBackend.Instance.GetStorage().GetReferenceFromUrl(resourcesURL);

        StorageProgress<Firebase.Storage.DownloadState> progressHandler = new StorageProgress<Firebase.Storage.DownloadState>(state =>
        {
            Debug.Log(String.Format ("Progress: {0} of {1} bytes transferred.", state.BytesTransferred, state.TotalByteCount));

            UpdateProgress(state.BytesTransferred / state.TotalByteCount);
        });

        Task dwnTask = fileRef.GetFileAsync
        (
            saveToPath, 
            progressHandler, 
            CancellationToken.None
        );

        dwnTask.ContinueWith(resultTask => 
        {
            if (!resultTask.IsFaulted && !resultTask.IsCanceled) 
            {
                ResetView();
                Debug.Log("Download finished!");
            }
            else
            {
                ResetView();
                Debug.Log("Download fail!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Unity version is 5.5.0f3
Firebase Unity SDK version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be doing anything wrong at all.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225307/firebase-storage-download-file-with-progress-does-not-fire-live-unity-c), this is a Firebase bug that is to be addressed in the next Firebase update.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try with an IEnumerator, this is my code with the storage progress working:

```
protected IEnumerator downloadObject(string target_file, string target_path, int item_index)
{
    if (target_file != "")
    {
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

        string local_url = target_path.Replace("\\", "/").Replace("//", "/");
        StorageReference storage_ref =
            storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(FB_Conf.gsURL + target_file);

        Task task = null;
        try
        {
            task = storage_ref.GetFileAsync(local_url,
                new Firebase.Storage.StorageProgress<DownloadState>((DownloadState state) =>
            {
            // called periodically during the download
                long tbyte = state.TotalByteCount;
                file_progress = (float)state.BytesTransferred / (float)tbyte;
            }), CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {                
            Debug.Log("Get file async error: " + exc.Message);
        }

        if (task != null)
        {
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted);
            task.ContinueWith((resultTask) =>
            {
                if ((resultTask.IsFaulted) || (resultTask.IsCanceled))
                {
                    error_count++;
                    string msg = (resultTask.IsCanceled) ? "Download error." : "";
                    if ((resultTask.Exception != null) &&
                        (resultTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count > 0) &&
                        (resultTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0] is Firebase.Storage.StorageException))
                        msg = ((Firebase.Storage.StorageException)resultTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0]).HttpResultCode.ToString();
                    else if (resultTask.Exception != null)
                        msg = resultTask.Exception.Message;                        
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            error_count++;
        }
    }
}
```