# Looking for a way to add a progress bar for asynchronic task (Unity, C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine, asynchronous, task, progress-bar

I'm pretty new to writing asynchronous stuff in Unity. It is pretty easy to create a progress bar for asynchronous operation, but when it comes to doing it for the asynchronous task I'm not even sure when to start :(

```c#
public async void GetPhotoFromAndroidAndAddTexture(RawImage mainImage, string path)
{
    await AddTextureToImage(mainImage, path);
}


public async Task<Texture2D> GetTextureFromAndroid(string path)
{
    if(path != "" && path != " ")
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            path = "file://" + path;
        #endif

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path);

        var asyncOperation = www.SendWebRequest();

        while(!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            await Task.Delay( 1000/30 );
        }

        return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("The path is not correct!");
        return null;
    }
}

public async Task AddTextureToImage(RawImage mainImage, string path)
{
    IProgress<int> progress;
    Texture2D photoFromDevice = await GetTextureFromAndroid(path);

    float textureH = photoFromDevice.height;
    float textureW = photoFromDevice.width;

    float aspectRat = textureH > textureW ? textureH/textureW : textureW/textureH;

    mainImage.GetComponent<AspectRatioFitter>().aspectRatio = aspectRat;
    mainImage.texture = photoFromDevice;
}
```

While the photo from android is being add as a texture I want to create a progress bar.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Comment: async always has the issues of multi-threading ... why don't you use a Coroutine (`IEnumerator`) as usually shown in the [examples](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I can see no reason in your code why you should be using `async` at all. The only thing you actually are waiting for is the `UnityWebRequest`. `async` hasn't really any advantage over a simple [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)(`IEnumerator`) here.

In addition `async` stuff always also brings the problem of multi-threading ... Unity isn't thread safe so most of the API can only be used in the Unity mainthread.

---

You should rather stick to a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```c#
// wherever you want to show/use the progress
public float progress;

public void GetPhotoFromAndroidAndAddTexture(RawImage mainImage, string path)
{
    StartCoroutine(AddTextureToImage(mainImage, path));
}

public IEnumerator AddTextureToImage(RawImage mainImage, string path)
{
    Texture2D photoFromDevice;

    if (path != "" && path != " ")
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        path = "file://" + path;
#endif

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path);

        var asyncOperation = www.SendWebRequest();

        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            // wherever you want to show the progress:
            progress = www.downloadProgress;

            yield return null;
            // or if you want to stick doing it in certain intervals
            //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }

        // you should also check for errors
        if(www.error != null) 
        {
            Debug.LogError("Something went wrong loading!", this);
            yield break;
        }

        photoFromDevice = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("The path is not correct!", this);
        yield break;
    }

    float textureH = photoFromDevice.height;
    float textureW = photoFromDevice.width;

    float aspectRat = textureH > textureW ? textureH / textureW : textureW / textureH;

    mainImage.GetComponent<AspectRatioFitter>().aspectRatio = aspectRat;
    mainImage.texture = photoFromDevice;
}
```

---

Alternatively often recommended is a kind of "dispatcher" or I prefer to call it a main thread worker where you can pass actions from other threads back to the main thread like e.g.

```c#
private ConcurrentQueue<Action> callbacks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

private void Update()
{
    while(callbacks.TryDequeue(var out a))
    {
        // Invokes the action in the main thread
        a?.Invoke();
    }
}

// example method to call
private void UpdateProgressBar(float progress)
{
    // use progress
}

public async Task<Texture2D> GetTextureFromAndroid(string path)
{
    if(path != "" && path != " ")
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            path = "file://" + path;
        #endif

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path);

        var asyncOperation = www.SendWebRequest();

        while(!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            // add a callback for the main thread using a lambda expression
            callbacks.Add(()=> { UpdateProgressBar(www.downloadProgress); });
            await Task.Delay( 1000/30 );
        }

        return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("The path is not correct!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

A cool way to have a simple progress bar for example can be achieved by using an [`UI.Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Image.html) with

- `Image Type` = Filled
- `Fill Method` = Horizontal
- `Fill Origin` = Left

now all you have to do is update the `image.fillAmount`

Comment: Yes, I think this is a very good suggestion and I will rewrite this function to coroutine. I'm still very curious how to get a progress of the async Task to use it, for example, with Firebase calls.

Comment: there you would probably use e.g. [`GetFileAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225307/firebase-storage-download-file-with-progress-does-not-fire-live-unity-c) and pass in a handler method you can [dispatch](https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher/blob/master/UnityMainThreadDispatcher.cs) back to the main thread

Comment: *`async hasn't really any advantage over async`* I think you meant `IEnumerator` or `Coroutine` there.

Answer (score 0):

Today I would suggest you to use [UniTask library](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask). It allows to use Coroutines as async methods and vice versa

Then you could write something like this:

```
// Also, you can use Progress.CreateOnlyValueChanged<float>(...)
var progress = Progress.Create<float>(x => {
     // Do something with progress...
     Debug.Log(x);
});

var request = await UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path)
    .SendWebRequest()
    .ToUniTask(progress: progress);
return DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(request);
```